# How to count RSpec examples filtered with :focus in a git hook?

Tags: ruby, git, rspec, rspec3

I am trying to write a Git pre-commit hook that would not let the user commit if there is an example that is tagged with `:focus`.

Using RSpec's API (okay even if it is private), is there any way to find out the number of examples with the `:focus` filter?

I found the [example_count-instance_method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/World#example_count-instance_method). It could be useful but I'm not sure how it can be called from an external script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is](https://github.com/hallucinations/overcommit-hooks/blob/master/.git-hooks/pre_commit/ensure_focus_free_specs.rb) an [Overcommit](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit) pre_commit hook that uses RSpecs private API to find out specs with `:focus` filter:

```
require 'rspec'

module Overcommit
  module Hook
    module PreCommit
      # NOTE: This makes use of many methods from RSpecs private API.
      class EnsureFocusFreeSpecs < Base
        def configure_rspec(applicable_files)
          RSpec.configure do |config|
            config.inclusion_filter = :focus
            config.files_or_directories_to_run = applicable_files
            config.inclusion_filter.rules
            config.requires = %w(spec_helper rails_helper)
            config.load_spec_files
          end
        end

        def run
          configure_rspec(applicable_files)

          return :pass if RSpec.world.example_count.zero?

          files = RSpec.world.filtered_examples.reject {|_k, v| v.empty?}.keys.map(&:file_path).uniq
          [:fail, "Trying to commit focused spec(s) in:\n\t#{files.join("\n\t")}"]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than calling RSpec Ruby code, I'd do it through RSpec's command-line interface using the `--dry-run` flag. Here's a pre-commit hook that does it that way:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! (rspec --dry-run --no-color -t focus:true 2>&1 | grep -q '^0 examples'); then
  echo "Please do not commit RSpec examples tagged with :focus."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I already had it working this way. But was considering a pure Ruby approach if possible since I was using [OverCommit](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit).

Comment: Though this isn't what OP was after, I like this solution. Thanks! However, the grep pattern should be changed to `'^0 examples'` so that it does not return a false negative when the number of focused tests ends in a zero.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this will help or answer the question, but I currently use [this set of githooks](https://github.com/bobgilmore/githooks) to make sure I don't commit obvious mistakes, and this [pull request](https://github.com/bobgilmore/githooks/pull/61) adds a check for `:focus`/`focus: true`/`:focus => true` in RSpec files.

Comment: I thought it would be better if RSpec is aware of the filters. This will help us to overcome issues like adding  a `:focus` in a code comment failing the git-hook.

Comment: BTW, you may want to consider `:focus => true` as well in your commit hook.

Comment: @hallucinations, nice pick up: I'd completely forgotten about hashrockets.  Fixed.