# How can I count the number of examples in my RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to count how many tests are in a directory without running the tests.

I tried something similar to what I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409804/how-to-count-rspec-examples-filtered-with-focus-in-a-git-hook), but wasn't able to print anything other than `0`.

---

This is what I tried (with and without the commented out config stuff):

```rb
task 'count_specs' do
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.pattern = 'features/**/*_spec.rb'
    # config.inclusion_filter.rules
    # config.filter_run focus: true
    # config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
    # config.inclusion_filter.rules
    config.requires = ['spec_helper']

    config.load_spec_files

    puts 'count of examples'
    puts config.files_to_run

  puts RSpec.world.example_count
  end

  puts 'count of examples'
  puts RSpec.world.example_count
end
```

How can I create a task that counts how many examples match a specific pattern?

I want to run this against two directories and compare the result.

Comment: You could try and use the [`--dry-run` option](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/command-line/dry-run-option) From the documentation Use the --dry-run option to have RSpec print your suite's formatter output
without running any examples or hooks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In RSpec 3 there is a `--dry-run` option which print your suite's formatter output without running any examples or hooks.

```
rspec --dry-run
```

If you need to have the count of examples in your ruby script:

```
output = `bundle exec rspec --dry-run | grep 'examples, 0 failures'`
example_count = output.split(' ').first.to_i
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to get the example_count programmatically. I can do it manually, but I'm trying to find a way to do it using the RSpec object.

Comment: Don't need `it "fails in example" do; fail; end`. It made +1 example

Comment: @carterw485 What you mean by counting programmatically? You mean a variable named `example_count` inside your ruby code to save example counts?

Comment: Yeah. I want to use whatever RSpec uses to count the examples. `RSpec.world.example_count` should work, but getting RSpec to update it is what I'm having a hard time with.

Comment: @carterw485 Check the updated answer. does this work?

Answer (score 2):

```
RSpec.configuration.world.example_count
```

This is undocumented so it could break in future releases.
Note that this is the cumulative number of tests that have run, so the number isn't accurate until the after every test has run.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is some specific RSpec method for this but I suggest this script:

```
Dir["**/*_spec.rb"].map { |path| File.read(path) }.join.scan(/(  it)|(  scenario)/).count
```

It is very naive but reliable.

This variant search `"  it"` and `"  scenario"`, but you can change pattern if you like.

This variant works only for tests without blocks like

```
RSpec.describe 'smth' do
  array.each do |i|
    it { should_smth }
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are shared example groups or examples defined with loops.

Comment: @SajadRastegar, thanks, you're right. I added these limitations to the answer

Comment: I have many different indentations of `it`. I could check for a lot of them, but I want to just hook into whatever RSpec already does in order to count them.